# Derivation of Born's Approximation in 1D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, perturbation-theory, greens-functions

I'm studying Quantum Mechanics and I'm curious about something related to Scattering Theory: Griffiths has a derivation from the Green's function to the Born's approximation in 3D but I was wondering how this looks in 1D? Specifically using the Green's function defined in
$$G(x,x')=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2ik}e^{ik(x-x')} & x>x' \\
\frac{1}{2ik}e^{-ik(x-x')} & x<x'.
\end{cases}$$